# How can we show our end-users that we are trusted by a bank?

Tags: certificates, account-security, identification, identity-management

We are developing an website which serves end users of many organizations
(banks  , municipalities etc).

We have already setup meetings with the banks and they've agreed to work with us.

Ok so let's say that a user `user1` of bank `bank1` is entering `bank1's` website - then he sees a legit certificate of `bank1` and a link for `newService1` -  : "*For using the new service please click here*"

This way - `user1` can be sure that the new service is trusted by `bank1` since `bank1` showed the link to `user1`.

**Question**

But what about the scenario where `user1` has entered `newService1's` website directly and NOT via `bank1` ? How can I show the user that `newService1's` website is trusted via `bank1` ?

Sure I can create a link (in `newService1's` website) which says : "This service is trusted by `bank1` - click here to see confirmation page in `bank1's` website".

Are  there any other trust mechanism which  `newService1's` website can implement to show `user1` that `newService1's` is trusted by `bank1` ?

NB
By `trust` I mean some kind of proof for `user1` that `bank1` has agreed to work with `newService1's`  .

Comment: OAuth with the bank. I'm not sure that there could be any other way to establish trust with a 3rd party.

Comment: Then it's a messaging problem. Get the bank to host a page describing the relationship and link to it on your site.

Comment: Another what-if: a phisher craft an email pretend to be `newService1's`

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible in your scenario, you might want to "multi-host" your service, under a subdomain of their domain.
E.g. `newService1.bank1.com`, and have them provide you with their own HTTPS certificate.

This creates an environment where you not only *trusted*, but it is THEIR service - at least from the perspective of the user, especially if you provide whitelabel branding, their logo, etc.

Note that in this case, you should isolate the bank from other tenants' service - on the backend as much as is feasible, but especially from the user's PoV. E.g. don't make the user re-select which is his bank, or any other bank-defined configuration, you need to function as if you ARE the bank's system. Or if you send out emails to users, these should be identified as the bank's newservice.

(P.S. this also can give you some great marketing tools, onboarding options, and easier to close the sale with many organizations... )